# How to read serialized object with a method taking generic type by Scala/Kryo?

Tags: scala, kryo

Use Kryo to read serialized object is easy when I know the specific class type, but if I want to create a method that takes simple generic type, how to do it?
I have code that can not be compiled:

```
def load[T](path: String): T = {
    val instantiator = new ScalaKryoInstantiator
    instantiator.setRegistrationRequired(false)
    val kryo = instantiator.newKryo()
    val input = new Input(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path)))
    kryo.readObject[T](input, classOf[T])
}
```

The error I got is:

```
class type required but T found
    kryo.readObject[T](input, classOf[T])
```

I know what the error means, but don't know the right way to fix it.

The code is modified by my original type-specific code:

```
def load(path: String): SomeClassType = {
    val instantiator = new ScalaKryoInstantiator
    instantiator.setRegistrationRequired(false)
    val kryo = instantiator.newKryo()
    val input = new Input(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path)))
    kryo.readObject(input, classOf[SomeClassType])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer, the key is `ClassTag`:

```
def load[M: ClassTag](path: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[M]): M = {
    val instantiator = new ScalaKryoInstantiator
    instantiator.setRegistrationRequired(false)
    val kryo = instantiator.newKryo()
    val input = new Input(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(path)))
    kryo.readObject(input, tag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[M]])
}
```

In some threads, the last line is:

```
kryo.readObject(input, tag.runtimeClass)
```

This doesn't work in my case, it has to be:

```
tag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[M]]
```